# how to access SSM params from CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, ssm

In my samTemplate I have some parameters defined so in my CodePipeline (CloudFormation step) I would like to override those params with SSM values.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this in the sam template:

```
Parameters:
  S3Bucket:
   Type : 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
   Default: "KEY_NAME"
```

KEY_NAME is the key in ssm, why its called Default I have no idea?